# Why do T-test Assuming Equal Population Variance and T-Test Not Assuming Equal Variance give the same t-statistic?

Tags: t-test

**When performing these two tests on the very same populations both times:**

- T-test Assuming *Equal* Variances
- T-test *Not Assuming Equal* Variances

**Why do both tests generate the same observed t-statistic**?

Supposedly, the formulas for calculating the observed t-statistic differ for these two tests. So I'm curious why I get the same observed t-statistic (`t Stat`) in the output from *Microsoft Excel's Data Analysis Add-In*.

---

- T-test Assuming Equal Variances:

$$ t=\frac{(\overline{x}_{1}-\overline{x}_{2})-(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2})}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_{1}}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_{2}}}} $$

- T-test Not Assuming Equal Variances:

$$ t=\frac{(\overline{x}_{1}-\overline{x}_{2})-(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2})}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2(n_{1}-1)+s_2^2(n_{2}-1)}{n_{1}+n_{2}-2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{1}}+\frac{1}{n_{2}}}}} $$

---

Population data:

```
Population A    Population B
-1.235671223    4.15960852
-0.761968905    1.310399095
0.941679605     -1.07118374
-1.378594308    -1.140884186
-0.701344758    7.340783069
0.470609188     -0.337045646
-0.455034508    8.506507035
0.98726877      3.09472358
-0.265557251    8.131838266
0.645189392     3.176737606
```

Observed T-statistics:

```
t Stat (Assuming Equal Variance): -2.89968750779
t Stat (Not Assuming Equal Variance): -2.89968750779
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the sample sizes are the same:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{s^2_1(n-1) + s^2_2(n-1)}{n+n-2}}*\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}} =$$

$$ \sqrt{\frac{(s^2_1 + s^2_2)(n-1)}{2(n-1)}}*\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} = $$

$$ \sqrt{\frac{(s^2_1 + s^2_2)}{1}}*\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} = $$

$$ \sqrt{\frac{(s^2_1 + s^2_2)}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{s^2_1}{n} + \frac{s^2_2}{n}}$$